# Deploy multiple instances of the same microservices in the same umbrella chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have umbrella chart to install all my microservices (charts) together. I have one microservice that i want to upload 3 diffrent instance of him with diffrent configuration to every environment. In each microservice chart i change some values (with the if option) in accordance to the environment.

I want to be able to upload 3 instance of the same app and then pass env from the umbrella to each microservice chart instance so i could difiened diffrent things between each instance (also with the if option).

To sum up i want to know if it possible to declare in the umbrella chart few instance of the same microservice chart and if so how to pass env to each of the diffrent instance chart

I upload my microservices charts to nexus repo and install the umbrella chart with argo cd

this is the umbrella chart:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: umbrella-chart
version: 1.0.0
description: A Helm umbrella chart containing three instances of a     microservice.

dependencies:
  - name: microservice-1
    version: 1.0.0
    repository: https://nexus-repo/microservice-instance1
    alias: microservice-1-instance-1

  - name: microservice-1
    version: 1.0.0
    repository: https://nexus-repo/microservice-instance1
    alias: microservice-1-instance-2

  - name: microservice-1
    version: 1.0.0
    repository: https://nexus-repo/microservice-instance1
    alias: microservice-1-instance-1-3

  - name: microservice-2
    version: 1.0.0
    repository: https://nexus-repo/microservice-instance2

  - name: microservice-3
    version: 1.0.0
    repository: https://nexus-repo/microservice-instance3
```

and the values file of the umbrella:

```
microservice-1-instance-1:
  instance: 1
microservice-1-instance-2:
  instance: 2
microservice-1-instance-3:
  instance: 3
```

Comment: I'd expect it would work pretty much exactly as you show it.  Is there a more specific problem you're running into?  (Note, IME there are some practical problems with using umbrella charts this way – if each service is supposed to have a separate in-cluster data store, for example, they'll get combined – and you might find a dedicated tool like Helmfile or Helmsman a better match for this use case.)